# Works on iPhone Simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimageview

Here I addsubviews (UIImageViews) it all works on the simulator but not on the device (iOS 4.1) wtf!?

```
- (void)addChips:(int)value {
UIImage *chipImage;
switch (value) {
    case 5:
        chipImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5chip"];
        break;
    case 25:
        chipImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"25chip"];
        break;
    case 100:
        chipImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"100chip"];
        break;
    case 500:
        chipImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"500chip"];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

int chipCount = [chipsOnBet count];
UIImageView *addChip = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:chipImage];
addChip.opaque = YES;
addChip.frame = CGRectMake((kStackOffset * chipCount) + 131, 268, 57, 57);
[self.view addSubview:addChip];
[chipsOnBet addObject:addChip];
[addChip release];
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Make sure you write the correct file names, iOS is case sensitive, simulator is not.
2. Make sure you have the proper retina files if you test on iPhone4

Comment: Case Sensitivity solved a similar problem for me - you can use the lowercaseString or uppercaseString function to get it to be uniform. Thanks Alin

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer in the documentation:

> Case-sensitivity: iPhone OS uses a
>   case-sensitive file system, unlike the
>   Simulator which uses a
>   case-insensitive file system by
>   default. Make sure the
>   case-sensitivity of resources accessed
>   within code matches the filename
>   case-sensitivity.
>
> For example, if our filename is
>   "YourExampleImage.png":
>
> Good: [UIImage
>   imageNamed:@"YourExampleImage.png"]
>
> Bad: [UIImage
>   imageNamed:@"YourExampleImage.PNG"]
>
> Bad: [UIImage
>   imageNamed:@"yourexampleimage.png"]

So I just have to ensure my image names are the same case as my resources. So in my case I should of put 5Chip instead of 5chip.

Comment: Whether the simulator is case-sensitive should depend on your Mac's FS. You can set up HFS+ to be case sensitive, but by default it's case insensitive but case preserving...

Answer (score 0):

You are going to use your image, names only. Not with image extension. You should use the full image name as

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
```

Make sure image name is the be same as you stored it in the resource folder.

Comment: Since the introduction iOS4 you no longer have to put the file extension if your referring to a resource loaded in your project