# iOS UIImage returns null

Tags: ios, uiimage

Why is this not working?

```
//set up check mark image
        imgCheckMark = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark.png"];
        vImgCheckMark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imgCheckMark];
        NSLog(@"%@", imgCheckMark);
```

I keep getting null in the console. The image is in the bundle, I can view it in editor.

Comment: Try @"checkmark" instead. If that doesn't work, look at the project settings. It may be in the project, but it might not be included as a resource.

Comment: Also double-check spelling and capitalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the image `Checkmark.png` from the project
2. add it back and try it
3. Make sure that the image is in the project folder[while adding check
   copy items into destination group (if needed)]
4. Make sure the image name is exactly the same as in the file

Comment: Turns out when I imported the file it imported to my test and not the project. Doh, should of picked that up as it happened with a couple of other imports as well. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 1):

Check the filename for case sensitivity. If your file is Checkmark.png then it will not work properly on the device. This questions has a few more details:

[Works on iPhone Simulator but not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050342/works-on-iphone-simulator-but-not-on-device)